# Proving that the equation $8x^4-8x+7=0$ has no real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to prove that the equation $8x^4-8x+7=0$ has no real roots.

My work:

i) for $x\leq 0,$ expression $8x^4-8x+7>0$,

ii) for $x\geq 1,$ expression $8x(x^3-1)+7>0$,

iii) for $0<x<1$?  I can't go further. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: We know the function is positive at $x=0$, and that it tends to positive infinity both as $x\to +\infty$ and as $x\to -\infty$.  I would try to identify the minimum value of $f(x) = 8x^4 - 8x + 7$ using a little calculus.  That is, if the minimum value is positive, it would mean the function is positive everywhere on the real line.

Comment: @hardmath This is specifically tagged as algebra-precalculus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$8x^4-8x+7=8(x^2-1/2)^2+8(x-1/2)^2+3> 3>0.$$

Answer (score 4):

For iii)

We have
$$\begin{align}8x^4-8x+7&=7x^4+x^4-7x-x+7\\&=7x^4-x(1-x^3)+7(1-x)\\&=7x^4-x(1-x)(1+x+x^2)+7(1-x)\\&=7x^4+(1-x)(7-x-x^2-x^3)\end{align}$$

You should be able to prove that this is positive.

Answer (score 2):

If
$f(x)
=8x^4-8x+7
$,
$f(0) = 7$
and
$f(1) = 1$.

Also

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=8x^4-8x+7\\
&=8x(x^3-1)+7\\
&=8x(x-1)(x^2+x+1)+7\\
&=-8x(1-x)(x^2+x+1)+7\\
\end{array}
$

For $0 < x < 1$,
$(x-\frac12)^2 \le \frac14$
since
$-\frac12 \le x-\frac12 \le \frac12$
for $0 \le x \le 1$
and
$0 \le x(1-x) \le \frac14$
since

$\begin{array}\\
x(1-x)
&=x-x^2\\
&=-(x^2-x)\\
&=-(x^2-x+\frac14-\frac14)\\
&=-((x-\frac12)^2-\frac14)\\
&=\frac14-(x-\frac12)^2\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
since
$1 \le 1+x+x^2 \le 3$,
$0
\le 8x(1-x)(1+x+x^2)
\le 8(\frac14)(3)
=6
$,
so
$f(x) \ge 1$
for $0 \le x \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

With calculus: set $f(x)=8x^4-8x+7$, so
$$
f'(x)=8(4x^3-1)
$$
which only vanishes at $x=4^{-1/3}$. So this is the unique point of minimum.

What's $f(4^{-1/3})$?